# In Json.Net (NewtonSoft.Json) Array is being serialized as JObject if added with TypeNameHandling.All

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, casting, json.net

I am serializing an Array of Customers with Serialization settings having  TypeNameHandling.All. When I deserialize that serialized string to JArray it throws an InvalidCast Exception.

Following is the Sample Code:

```
   var customers = new Customer[1];
   customers[0] = _customer;
    
   JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };   

   var serializedArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers, serializerSettings);
    
   try
   {
      var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(serializedArray, serializerSettings);
   }
   catch (InvalidCastException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("InvalidCastException >> " + ex.Message);
      // Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.'
    
 }
```

The Exception is not thrown if TypeNameHandling is not Added.
Why is the Exception thrown if serialized with TypeNameHandling and what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Because it tries to cast your `Customer[]` (defined in file) to `JArray` (defined in the code). If you use typed deserialization your types should also match. This should work

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer[]>(serializedArray, serializerSettings);
```

There is a difference how Json.Net recognize and parse the JSON string.

When you use `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All` the output string is the object, JToken of type JObject is applied.

```
{
  "$type": "Customer[], NewtonsoftSample",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$type": "Customer, NewtonsoftSample",
      "Name": "Simple Customer",
      "Id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

If you use `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None` the JSON string has a form of array, JArray is applied

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Simple Customer",
    "Id": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: if it it tries to cast `Customer[]`  to `JArray`  then the exception message should be 

"Unable to cast object of type 'Customers[]' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.'"

Comment: it happens because JSON string has a different format (object vs array). So default `JsonConvert.Deserialize` uses `JObject` implementation but not `JArray`. So you cannot cast directly JObject to JArray. When you use custom type (`Customer[]`), it creates  instance of this type directly and populates it.